# need the two blocks to be aligned on the right side of the text - possible?

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite

Been optimizing some stuff using sprites and ran into this problem... I need the two blocks to be aligned to the right of the text, but no matter what I do they start left aligned on a new line underneath it.  Using position:absolute appears to work in my editor, but when publishing it does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">    
a.facebook{margin:0 5px 0 0;float:left;display:block;width:30px;height:30px;background:url(social.png) no-repeat 0 0;background-position:0px -38px;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-10000px;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;}
a.twitter{margin:0 5px 0 0;float:left;display:block;width:30px;height:30px;background:url(social.png) no-repeat 0 0;background-position:-30px -38px;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-10000px;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>this is a test
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://test.com')" title="Find us on Facebook!" class="facebook">Find us on Facebook!</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://test.com')" title="Find us on Twitter!" class="twitter">Find us on Twitter</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a live demo on your site (that shows the relevant images), or perhaps a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question, I think you're looking for `float:right`, but notice that floats float relatively to the elements that **follow** them, so you need to place the links before the text.

**edit: more data**
If you want blocks to be inserted into other elements as if they were part of the text, you should make their `display:inline-block` (in IE6 this only works for elements that are inline by default). But then they'll appear in the position they're inserted into, not floating.

Comment: That somewhat works, but I need to two blocks to be inline with the text... if I use the float right then it positions to the extreme far right of the page not 'after' the text.

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is 'this is a test' with two 30x30 block elements to follow inline to the right of that as if they were part of the sentence.